# How to set opacity for a textview inside a fragment while fling?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How to give opacity to a textview inside a fragment?

Initially i having a horizontal circular ViewPager, and TextView inside my fragment should fade in and fade out when focusing to the screen and leaving the screen respectively.

I done some experiment wit onTouchListener but i didnt get anywhere. I tried to set an hardcoded alpha value too, but its not working as expected.

```
float prev = 0;
@Override
public void getPositionValue(float x1,float x2){
    AppUtils.alphaCalculator(x2,prev,deviceWidth);
    prev = x2;
    int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    CustomViewPagerAdapter customViewPagerAdapter = (CustomViewPagerAdapter) viewPagerAdapter;
    ImageSliderFragment fragment = customViewPagerAdapter.getFragment(index);
    fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(50);
    fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.head_data).invalidate();
    ImageSliderFragment fragment2 = customViewPagerAdapter.getFragment(index+1);
    fragment2.getView().findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(50);
    fragment2.getView().findViewById(R.id.head_data).invalidate();
}
```

Can anyone give some idea on how to achieve this...

According to kartheek, i able to get partiall, below is my code

```
if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.10f);
        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]

            if(position<0.1f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(1.0f);
            }else if(position<0.2f && position>0.1f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.68f);
            }else if(position<0.3f && position>0.2f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.55f);
            }else if(position<0.4f && position>0.3f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.45f);
            }else if(position<0.5f && position>0.4f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.38f);
            }else if(position<0.6f && position>0.5f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.30f);
            }else if(position<0.7f && position>0.6f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.22f);
            }else if(position<0.8f && position>0.7f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.15f);
            }else if(position<0.9f && position>0.8f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.10f);
            }else if(position<1.0f && position>0.9f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.05f);
            }

            if(position<-0.1f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(1.0f);
            }else if(position<-0.2f && position>-0.1f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.68f);
            }else if(position<-0.3f && position>-0.2f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.55f);
            }else if(position<-0.4f && position>-0.3f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.45f);
            }else if(position<-0.5f && position>-0.4f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.38f);
            }else if(position<-0.6f && position>-0.5f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.30f);
            }else if(position<-0.7f && position>-0.6f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.22f);
            }else if(position<-0.8f && position>-0.7f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.15f);
            }else if(position<-0.9f && position>-0.8f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.10f);
            }else if(position<-1.0f && position>-0.9f){
                view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.05f);
            }

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right
            view.findViewById(R.id.head_data).setAlpha(0.10f);
        }
```

Image focusing from right and leaving to right getting worked properly.

But not working in the either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by `ViewPager.PageTransformer`, it will give the callbacks when `fragments` are slided in the `ViewPager`. Here is a small example

```
public class SimplePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();


             if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]

                } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right
                }
        }
    }
```

You can find a [detail example](https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4) from this link.

Comment: Thanks Kartheek, will check and reply further.

Comment: developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer This helped... Thanks!!! :)